# 26' Maxxis Ikon 2.35 Bike slipped while pedalling

Tags: mountain-bike, tire, dirt-jumps

Long story short bought a new bike, went to bring it inside so hopped on it to ride it to the door, Pedaled hard on the pavement, and then all of a sudden the bike slipped under me.

Come to realize later they were running around 23 PSI ordered some DTH's to either try mixed setup or go full DTH for more grip on pavement, I have since pumped up the tyres but yet to ride it since I can't wear a helmet with the stitches lol.

Was the bike slipping due to the tyres and road surface or too low pressure? Or me simply being a moron? Struggling to understand if anyone has experience with Ikons on the pavement any info would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

For a Maxxis Ikon, 23psi is completely reasonable, in fact at that pressure they are probably offering near optimum grip.

While these are off road tires, they are pretty low profile and on pavement, even in the wet, there should be more than ample grip.

I commonly I ride these all year round, everything from concrete to roots and rocks in all conditions, find these in most situations often offer more grip than much burlier tires.  I will run these in at around 25(ish) psi depending on the conditions

Comment: For reference this is on a DJ, 23 PSI is pretty uncommon to my knowledge, not to mention as a heavier rider 23 PSI is way to little. Would you happen to be able to guess why I may have ate shit? Lol, it might just be as simple as I lost balance without knowing but it didn't feel like that.

Comment: Also a heavier rider, have been upwards of 120kgs at times riding these same tires. All be it, not a Dirt jumper but have these tires on 2 bikes (29x2.35).  One tubeless which I run between 22-25psi (have been down as low as 18psi) and one tubed running 26psi front and 28-30 rear.  Can't say why you ate the pavement, but pretty sure the combo of tire and pressure isn't more than coincidence.

Answer (score 0):

I routinely ride my MTB on roads with a range of tyres (from gravel tyres to those more meant for mud).  I typically ride to the trails, let some air out, then don't pump them back up before riding back.  Grip at trail pressure on paved surfaces is still very good; even if they're so soft they squirm, they don't let go.

So I reckon something else went wrong.  Perhaps an oil patch on the road or even the tyre, or slippery litter under your front wheel.  I assume it was the front that slipped as back wheel slides tend to be more recoverable, and only an issue when turning hard.

The one exception might be if you were riding on a very smooth paved surface, like a tiled path/patio, in the wet.  Not tyres will grip that well.

Comment: 30 degrees Celsius normal concrete parking lot. Dry perfect summer day. Haven't gotten a chance to get back on it but come to think as I've been tinkering with it, my rebound may have been wrong and the front bounced up front wheel turns and boom. After going back to the crash site and being pretty sure I have the fork at the right settings now nothing else seems.possible.